# two column journal LaTeX template without journal annotation?

Tags: two-column, templates, journal-publishing

I'm looking for a beautifully typeset two-column journal template, like this one from ACM:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-large-2-column-format-template/qwcgpbmkkvpq#.VtR5R5MrJdA

except that I don't want all the journal annotations that appear everywhere (e.g. ACM Transactions, Volume X, Issue Y). Is there a template like this available?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
 your text here
\end{document}
```

That is the most basic one that can be heavily extended using one of the many packages available on CTAN.

Comment: I'd like to get the same header formatting as the ACM theme I linked to above: same title/abstract formatting

Comment: @mvd Extend it using one of the many packages found on CTAN. I doubt, that there is something out there that resembles the template. Nobody even  really knows the definition of template.

Comment: Other answers will be more helpful than mine.